# In XML, one of the fields mandatory to fill in and adding attachments is also mandatory

Tags: java, xml, user-interface

I am new to `XML` Language. 
I am working on XML. and that XML is an input to one of the UI applications.
IN that UI applications, multiple tabs are presents. In that Tabs- `Notes` is one of the tabs.
Now I wanted to make that `Notes` tab as a mandatory field and mandatory to add attachment. But when I add the condition like mentioned below (`Condition:1`). I am getting (`Error:2`) as mentioned below. Please help me in this.

(Condition:1)-->

```
field type="component" 
component-name="CommentsAndAttachments"  
name="TEMP.COMMENTS" 
required="True"
```

(Error:2)-->

> "" is required

I am not able to fix this. Please help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you wrote is not XML. What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I was told it is an XML. As I have mentioned earlier, I am new to XML.  On the other hand, can you help me in this or no. Thanks

Comment: Hi Rama, I'm sorry to say but what you shared in your post is not XML. Can you give more specifics?

Comment: Hi David, The file has an extension of .xml and people are communicating it as an XML file. 
In the google also xml code is looking like this. 
<field type="component" required="True" component-name="CommentsAndAttachments" name="TEMP.COMMENTS"
        readonly="!IsEntySaved()">. Please let me know if you need any furhter details.